# How to add path to a js file

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have this Sipml-api.js inside the CI folder (specifically in the C:\wamp\www\arise\assets), I want to locate the Sipml.js and src/tinySIP/src/tsip_api.js which is also in the same folder.

Here's what I did but the result is **NOT FOUND!**

```js
var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
var __b_release_mode = false;
var tag_hdr = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
[base_url +'/SIPml.js', base_url + '/src/tinySIP/src/tsip_api.js'].forEach(function (file) {
    var tag_script = document.createElement('script');
    tag_script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    tag_script.setAttribute('src', file + "?svn=241");
    tag_hdr.appendChild(tag_script);
});
```

I don't know much about javascript so I was just experimenting.

My question is how to really add path to this (`Sipml.js and src/tinySIP/src/tsip_api.js`) files in the `Sipml-api.js`?

Comment: What errors to you get?

Comment: I got error 404, Not Found.

Comment: So inspect your DOM using the browser's tools to see what URL was generated instead of the one you were expecting.

Comment: What are you using to server the files? Is your server set up to server javascript files? From that directory? Your code looks good -- I have a feeling that this is more of a setup issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the below code works for you:

```
function getBaseUrl() {
    return (location.host !== 'localhost') ? location.origin : location.origin + '/' + location.pathname.split('/')[1].trim('/') + '/';
}

var base_url = getBaseUrl();
var __b_release_mode = false;
var tag_hdr = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
[base_url +'assets/SIPml.js', base_url + 'assets/src/tinySIP/src/tsip_api.js'].forEach(function (file) {
    var tag_script = document.createElement('script');
    tag_script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    tag_script.setAttribute('src', file + "?svn=241");
    tag_hdr.appendChild(tag_script);
});
```